# Selecting specific data using table joins

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to output some a user username from the user table by joining it from a questions table, the intention being I can show which user posted this specific question.

users with `id`, `username`

discussion_q `id`, `question_text`, `user_id`

Here is where I am at:

```
$sql = "SELECT q.id AS questionId, q.question_text AS questionText, q.user_id AS questionUserId, q.published AS questionPub, users.id AS userId 
                    FROM discussion_q 
                    JOIN users
                    ON questionUserId = userId
                    WHERE project_id = '$projectId'
                    ORDER BY published";
```

I am getting 0 results returned back to me of course. I am sure I have over engineered this or missed something simple?

Here is my php to return the results:

```
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo '<div class="twelve columns">
                  <p><a href=".php?project_id=' . $row['id'] .'">' . $row['question_text'] . '</a></p>
                  <p>' . $row['published'] . ' by ' . $row['username'] . '</p>
                  </div>';
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
```

So the end goal is to output the question_text with the username of the user who posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT q.id AS questionId, q.question_text AS questionText, q.user_id AS questionUserId, q.published AS questionPub, users.id AS userId 
                    FROM discussion AS q 
                    JOIN users
                    ON (q.user_id = users.id)
                    WHERE project_id = '$projectId'
                    ORDER BY published";
```

Comment: I still don't seem to be getting any results back with the Php let me run it through my DBM

Comment: I hope that helps?

Comment: Why on earth would I change my results function to an old method??

Comment: Can you also show how you define `$conn` ? I'll explain after that :)

Comment: I have resolved the issue now by your SELECT method. I don't need to alter the way its connecting or returning the results.

Comment: `$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);` - that won't work, since he's using mysqli_. If anything, that should have read as `$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);` but wouldn't have made a difference. I have taken that part out in an edit. Edit: @PhpDude I took that part out in an edit. http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42123591/3